# Can installing a new PSU cause CPU spikes/Firefox freezes?

Tags: windows-7, firefox, cpu, power-supply, freeze

After having my last PSU die on me, and then running on a borrowed 250W one for a few months, I finally got round to installing a new one. I inputted the wattage of all my current parts into a few sites and consistently kept coming up with 300W figures. To play it safe, I decided to buy a 550W Corsair VS550.

My CPU is a i3-2100 Dual Core at 3.1 GHz each. Since about a week after installing the VS550, CPU usage started to peak to crazy levels when using Firefox, after which it'd freeze and require a kill in Task Manager. This is usually triggered by either having a large amount of tabs open (usually more than 15) or just one or two on a really slow site. When opening Task Manager during or just before the freeze, Firefox shows around 25% of total CPU, although it has been as high as 60% in the past, and the first of the four cores of the CPU (two physical, two virtual) in particular seems most affected, rather than all of them taking equal strain. No other program registers as using significant amounts of CPU when this peak happens. Memory is usually hitting around 4-5GB, though this has never really been a problem as I have 16GB installed.

I can't recall having had this behavior happen before I installed the new PSU, and if it ever did happen it definitely wasn't as consistent. I'm always using the latest version of Firefox, currently that's 54.0.1 32-bit on a 64-bit Windows 7 OS.

Is it at all possible that the PSU could be causing these spikes/freezes? It was also my first time installing one, so is it also possible that it could be a bad install on my part that's at fault? If it's none of these, does anyone have any idea what could be causing it? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid the short answer is that your new PSU would just about have to be defective to cause anything remotely approaching these problems. And, if it were, the problems would very likely be much more severe (crashes, random shut downs, overheating components, etc). More than likely the problem lies elsewhere.

That said there are two main circumstances that could potentially cause this problem.

- PSU is not outputting voltage/amperage within acceptable ranges

  - It could be outputting low or high voltage intermittently or on only one pin or both. Short of connecting the power supply to a load tester there is no accurate way to identify such problems. The voltage detection of most motherboards is somewhat suspect and prone to malfunctioning due to the very problems they are meant to detect
- PSU is not fully cleaning power spikes and noise from building power

The PSU you mention does not have Active PFC (which helps significantly with both of these). It also is only 80 Plus White certified efficiency (the lowest) which itself isn't relevant but does indicate a rather low-end "bargain" unit. Corsair makes good power supplies (I use one in my own machine and suggest them for my clients)... but they make a wide range of products from bargain units like this one appears to be and the ultra-high-end enthusiast units.

In my experience, even power-users (and even many IT professionals) often underestimate how important a good power supply is for a computer. They also often mistakenly assume that wattage is the only thing that really matters. But you would likely be better off with a lower wattage power supply with Active PFC and at least 80 Plus Bronze efficiency certification.

All that said, the odds of this being a PSU problem are still quite low. If possible borrow another PSU from a friend and try it... just to fully eliminate it. But your time is likely better spent considering other possibilities.

It's worth noting that Firefox is known to have serious problems with heavy javascript on pages (and its cumulative with all other tabs). They supposedly fixed it in the most recent versions by allowing Firefox's javascript engine to spawn up to 4 separate threads but, after having used them recently for several months, your symptoms sound exactly like my own recent experience with Firefox. I suggest trying a different browser for a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you may want to run a few stress tests on your CPU to rule out any issue with the CPU itself being damaged, or the CPU cooler being underpowered and causing the CPU to throttle itself.

If you're running Firefox as 32-bit, then the max memory it can use is 4GB regardless of your OS. If you find that the CPU peaks and Firefox starts to stutter/freeze when it's approaching the 4GB limit, then that's a sure sign that Firefox is thrashing around trying to do garbage collection. As Cliff mentioned in his answer, Firefox can start to struggle when running 50+ tabs along with heavyweight addons, and this is true based on my own experiences too. Do what you can to cut down on open tabs (shove them into bookmarks for later), and disable any addons you don't need. Alternatively, try uninstalling the 32-bit version and try the 64-bit one.